# What is a regular expression for matching numbers divisible by 4?

Tags: regex, lex

I want to make a lexical analyzer that detects numbers divisible by 4.
Sample code -

```
%%
16(divisible by 4) {printf("divisible by 4 %s\n",yytext);}
%%
main()
{
        yylex();
}
```

Comment: Why would you want to check something like that with a regex???

Comment: @alfasin I am learning `lex/flex` in my compiler Design course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
%%  
[0-9]+  {int number = atoi(yytext); if((number % 4) == 0) printf("Div_4 %d\n", number);}
%%

main()
{
        yylex();
}
```

As `lex/flex` support C, so you can save the string as integer and then check it in C.

Comment: Since you didn't answer your own question (you found a solution, but it doesn't use regex...) you should accept the other answer assuming it's correct.

Comment: @alfasin: the other solution is not correct (for lex).

Answer (score 3):

## Divisibility by 4

The single-digit numbers which are divisible by 4 are 0, 4, and 8.

The two-digit numbers which are divisible by 4 can be divided into two groups:

```
12, 16, 32, 36, 52, 56, 72, 76, 92, 96
20, 24, 28, 40, 44, 48, 60, 64, 68, 80, 84, 88
```

Any number which is three or more digits and ends in any of these two-digit numbers is divisible by four.

Therefore, the regular expression should search for numbers of the form `\d*[02468][048]`, or the form `\d*[13579][26]`, or the single digit numbers `0`, `4`, and `8`.

## The Regex

This regular expression matches all numbers, positive or negative, which are divisible by 4:

```
-?(?:\d*[02468][048]|\d*[13579][26]|[048])
```

Note that this could match part of a number, such as `24` in `1245`. If you want to make sure that you only match an entire number, you could add negative look-around expressions:

```
(?<!\d)-?(?:\d*[02468][048]|\d*[13579][26]|[048])(?!\d)
```

or you could use word boundaries:

```
\b-?(?:\d*[02468][048]|\d*[13579][26]|[048])\b
```

Comment: explain your answer.

Comment: Those "regular expressions" will not work with (f)lex.

Comment: But someone with a few minutes to spare could translate them, while the other answer does not address the question.

Comment: @Amirmasudzarebidaki, that regex is for matching **binary** numbers that are divisible by 4. This question is about a regex for matching **base-10** numbers that are divisible by 4.

Comment: I guess this one might do: `^[02468]$|(\d*([02468][048]|[13579][26]))$`