# Regular expression for binary numbers which are divisible by 4

Tags: regex, binary

I want to create a regular expression to match the following:

> `L`: the set of all bit strings (i.e. strings over alphabet `{0,1}`) that are divisible by `4`

Comment: Wiktor, this is not a duplicate. The [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48352672/8534588) asks for a regex to match base-10 numbers that are divisible by 4, this questions asks for regex to match base-2 numbers that are divisible by 4.

Answer (score 4):

If a binary is divisible by four, the last two bits are zero. So you can use this Regex to match:

```
/.+00$/
```

or, if you want to check that it is indeed a binary number (only zeros and ones), you can use:

```
/[01]+00$/
```

If you also want to match `0` and `00`:

```
/^(00?|[01]+00)$/
```

if you don't want to match all zeros, you can use:

```
/(?=1)[01]+00$/
```

Comment: In fact it should be `^(0*1+0*)+00$`

Comment: I'd simply assume the other characters are valid and use `/00$/`.

Comment: @revo `0` is divisible by `4`.

Comment: It's Regular Expressions in theory. It needs to be defined over an alphabet. There is no character classes in theory.

Comment: @Poul now that I think about it, your regex does not match `0` or `00`. But as I read the question, both these strings should be part of `L`.

Comment: @shubham No since it doesn't accept `0100`. But `^(1*0*)*00$` is OK. It matches `00`, however.